# How to install ios app in physical device without developer account and without physical connection?

Tags: ios

I am planning to deliver the phase-1 changes for testing in the real device. But I have to share it to my team in another location. So **without physical connection**(without connecting the device into mac machine which runs xcode7 or later) and **without creating account in the apple developer program** is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible as you require a development account to provision the phone along with a physical connection to install the app to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Apple developer account is required but once you have developer account, you can distribute your app for **testing** among your testers **without a physical connection** using [testflight](https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).